# why value in a native select not binding to the fieldgroup vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

i have one native select branchStateSelect:

```
    branchStateSelect = new NativeSelect("State:");
    branchStateSelect.setImmediate(true);
    branchStateSelect.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
    branchStateSelect.setRequired(true);
    branchStateSelect.setNullSelectionItemId(0);
    branchStateSelect.setItemCaption(0, "--Select--");
    branchStateSelect.addValueChangeListener(fetchCityListener);
```

and there is another native select : this is binded to a fieldgroup

```
   communicationAddressStateSelect = new NativeSelect("State:");
    communicationAddressStateSelect.setRequired(true);
    communicationAddressStateSelect.setImmediate(true);
         communicationAddressStateSelect.setNullSelectionAllowed(true);

    communicationAddressStateSelect.setWidth(COMMON_FIELD_WIDTH);
    communicationAddressStateSelect.setEnabled(false);
```

and the city listener for state select :

```
     private ValueChangeListener fetchCityListener = new ValueChangeListener() {

    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getProperty().getValue() == null) {
                     //do nothing
        }
        else{
        communicationAddressStateSelect.setNullSelectionItemId(0l
        communicationAddressStateSelect.setItemCaption(0l,
                        "state1");
        communicationAddressStateSelect.select(0l);

                }
            }

        }}

    }
};
```

when I select branchstateselect native select
the value in the communicationAddressStateSelect is populated
but value binded to the fieldgroup is null???? why>?>>>
I want value 0L to be binded... what is the error

Comment: you set the nullSelectionItemId to "0" and select it.  so vaadin will return null and this is what get's stored.  this or your empty if-branch in the listener confuses me

Comment: empty if branch check if the value selected is null on which do nothing